# Django - Excluding some fields in Inline Admin Interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

In Django admin interface, Is to possible to exclude some of the fields in Inline?

Comment: There seems not any way suggested in the documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options

Comment: Apart from the very well-documented `exclude` option, that is.

Comment: hmm...i did not know that it was applicable in inlines too.

Answer (score 73):

with [exclude](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude) you can do it

ex:

```
class Book(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   short_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    exclude = ['short_description']
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Francisco Lavin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187291/django-excluding-some-fields-in-inline-admin-interface/4187480#4187480), you can exclude **"short_description" field** from your form by using **"fields"** with **"author"** and **"title"** as shown below:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   short_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    fields = ['author', 'title'] # Here
```

And also by adding **"editable=False"** to **"short_description" field**, you can exclude **"short_description" field** from your form as shown below (**"BookInline" class** is not needed):

```py
class Book(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)             # Here
   short_description = models.CharField(max_length=200, editable=False)
```