# django admin show related object inline (self referencing)

Tags: django-admin, django-1.4

I have a self referencing model like this:

```
class Item(models.model):
      parent = models.ForeignKey('Item',null=True,blank=True)
      field = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And I want to display the hierarchy in the admin, to do so I do:

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item
    can_delete = False

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      inlines = (ItemInline,)

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

However it does not work , when I try to acces an item in the admin it hangs endlessly but it I can access the list of items just fine.
However when I remove the inline it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the issue i was facing was due to the fact I tried to display the whole object , by restricting the fields displayed it worked.
I did it like this : [Django - Excluding some fields in Inline Admin Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187291/django-excluding-some-fields-in-inline-admin-interface)